# Display mysql JOIN data when one table returns empty row

Tags: mysql

I have a query for selecting data from two different tables using mysql cross join, but I get empty row for both tables when the first table is empty. Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 1) dummy 
CROSS JOIN(
    SELECT value 
    FROM tbl_settings AS X 
    WHERE settings='company_mail') X 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT email 
    FROM tbl_users AS Y 
    WHERE username='Flora')Y
```

I tried adding a dummy row first, but it didn't solve the issue. When tbl_settings is empty, tbl_users returns empty too even when there are data in it.

Comment: A cross join pairs each row of the two tables. If one of the tables is empty, what do you expect to pair with?

Comment: What result do you expect with an empty table? Maybe you should use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Barmar, The reason I used cross join was because I don't want to make a comparison or pair with an rows.

Comment: You can use `ON 1 = 1` in a `LEFT JOIN` to avoid comparing anything.

Comment: I tried that too and nothing changed

Comment: I tried that too and nothing changed

Comment: If the empty table is the first table you have to use `RIGHT JOIN`. Usually queries are written with the master table first and the referencing table second, so we use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT value value FROM tbl_settings WHERE settings='company_mail'
```

will return an empty resultset if the there is no row with `settings='company_mail'` in the table `tbl_settings`.
But if you use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(value) value FROM tbl_settings WHERE settings='company_mail'
```

you will get 1 row with `null` in the column value if the row does not exist.

So if you expect only 1 row max returned from `tbl_settings` you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT MAX(value) value FROM tbl_settings WHERE settings='company_mail') X 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT email FROM tbl_users WHERE username='Flora') Y
```

If you also expect only 1 row from `tbl_users` then it is simpler:

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT value FROM tbl_settings WHERE settings='company_mail') value, 
  (SELECT email FROM tbl_users WHERE username='Flora') email
```